# Truly Quiet Deja Dup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have set-up Deja Dup to take backup over a ssh connection on the LAN. At times when the link is down, Deja Dup pops out a box 'No route to host'.

Is there a way to avoid this? Like a -quiet switch?? Or at least redirect the output to some log-file?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to tell deja-dup to not display errors.  But modern versions of deja-dup (Ubuntu 12.04 or above) should not start a scheduled backup if it can't resolve the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect standard output this way:

```
<command> > <file>
```

To redirect standard error, use this:

```
<command> 2> <file>
```

To redirect both, use this:

```
<command> > <file> 2> <file>
```

If you don't want to actually save the file, you can redirect to /dev/null. Anything written there will simply disappear.

Comment: This is too general. My question was specifically was about Deja Dup -- the backup utility with a GUI.

Comment: So how about replacing `<command>` with `deja-dup`?

Comment: Then I will need to launch my command and not Deja Dup. Plus, I do not know if the No route is the error of Deja Dup.

Comment: I don't get it. If you type `deja-dup > /dev/null`, doesn't that start Deja Dup?

Comment: It might. But that is not how it operates. Deja Dup is kind of always on. It backs up at a particular schedule set up in the application itself

Comment: It has to be started somewhere, probably at login. Try checking startup applications in system settings. There might be a command that you can modify.

Comment: Elmer Startup Applications does not show Deja Dup. It must be a demon or something. And I am NOT saying that there is no way of doing it. But there seems to be a very tedious way of doing it. I wanted to know if there is an 'easy' way of doing it --- as in a setting in the preferences that I might have missed out on

Comment: In that case I think you may be out of luck. I was thinking about a "-quiet" switch as in a command line: "deja-dup -quiet".